# port forwarding multiple services with domain name on server

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I'm currently running a ubuntu server with multiple services on different ports(apache on 80, gitlab on 41990, and other python web service on 18992 for example)
I wonder is there any way to port forward these services with domain names( for example, http://gitlab.mydomain.me -> http://mydomain.me:41990 )
I've search through but only found solutions on single service...

Comment: Yes, this is possible. The solution to the problem is mod_proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http.

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

In ubuntu that will be with the sudo a2enmod mod_proxy_http command.

Your gitlab.mydomain.me domain virtual host configuration would look something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName gitlab.mydomain.me

    ProxyPass / http://mydomain.me:41990/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomain.me:41990/
</VirtualHost>
```